# What should 'git lfs lock' on a file not tracked by LFS do?

Tags: git-lfs

What should be the behavior of 'git lfs lock' if its called on a file not tracked by LFS? I did not see this addressed in the documentation

In my experiments with the command line, it allows me to lock a file that isn't tracked by LFS. It subsequently shows that lock when I do a 'git lfs locks'. However, if I do a 'git lfs ls-files' it does not show that file as being tracked.

Is that right?

git-lfs/2.13.3 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.16.2; git a5e6585)

Answer (score 1):

It is permissible to lock or unlock a file that is not actually tracked.  This can be useful because the file may exist in a different branch, or may have existed in a branch, but been deleted.  Therefore, lock operations should generally succeed so that locks can work across different branches with different files.

`git lfs ls-files` shows files that are tracked by Git LFS.  If the files are not tracked in the current branch, they won't be shown by Git LFS, even if they may be locked on the server.